# How to preserve EFLAGS changed in between a cmp and a conditional jump in Assembly x86?

Tags: assembly, x86

There's this situation when the `cmp` instruction is distant from the conditional jump. I have to increment a variable and it must happen in between those two instructions because I want to keep track of how many times that `je` instruction is issued. I control the code, and thought of doing that by inserting an `add` before the `je`:

```
 B+>0x7ffff7ffb03e      cmp    eax,ecx                                                                       │
│   0x7ffff7ffb040      nop                                                                                  │
│   0x7ffff7ffb041      nop                                                                                  │
│   0x7ffff7ffb042      nop                                                                                  │
│   0x7ffff7ffb043      nop                                                                                  │
│   0x7ffff7ffb044      add    DWORD PTR [rsi+0x20],0x1                                                      │
│   0x7ffff7ffb048      je     0x7ffff7ffb36c
```

The problem is that even when both `eax` and `ecx` are equal and the `ZF` and `PF` flags are set, they're overwritten by the following `add` operand so the `je` is never triggered. How do I preserve the EFLAGS in this situation?

Comment: If you don't care about performance `pushf` and `popf` . Otherwise you could move the DWORD value at `[rsi+0x20]` to an unused register, use LEA to add 1 to the register and then move the value back to `[rsi+0x20]` . LEA and MOV instructions don't modify the flags.

Comment: If there aren't any other branches in there, just move the increment before the compare.

Comment: If you have a spare register, `mov`-load / `lea` / `mov`-store.

Comment: @prl it's dynamically generated, I can't spot where the `cmp` will be.

Comment: The `mov-load / lea / mov-store` seemed to solve the problem despite increasing the code. It's no big deal for me. Thank you all for the suggestion!!